# Exception when trying to deserialize object with HttpResponseHeaders property

Tags: c#, serialization, http-headers, httpresponse

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize an object of a class that has a property of type System.Net.Http.Headers.**HttpResponseHeaders**, but I'm getting an exception like this:

> "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot create and
> populate list type System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpResponseHeaders.
> Path 'httpResponseHeaders', line 1, position 31.'

My code is like this:

```
//Template class with properties to be serialized/deserialized
public class Response
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public HttpResponseHeaders httpResponseHeaders { get; set; }
}

//Method for creating an object of type HttpResponseHeaders
static HttpResponseHeaders CreateHttpResponseHeaders()
{
    var myType = typeof(HttpResponseHeaders);
    var types = Array.Empty<Type>();
    var constructorInfoObject =
        myType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, types, null);

    return (HttpResponseHeaders)constructorInfoObject.Invoke(null);
 }

//Serialization/Deserialization Test
var response = new Response();
response.Id = 1;

response.httpResponseHeaders = CreateHttpResponseHeaders();
response.httpResponseHeaders.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Negotiate"));


var responseSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
var responseDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseSerialized);
```

The `HttpResponseHeaders` class is sealed and has no constructor and the version is Assembly System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0.

I manage to serialize, but on deserialize the exception described above pops. Does anyone have an idea how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more context and code? In order to be able to help you we need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same issue--I worked around by using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>` instead for now.